# How to concate 2 flowfiles in Apache NiFi based on the column value (csv)?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am new to NiFi, and I am currently working on a task where I have a flowfile:

"a","b","c","d" 
"abc","jfx","daw","123" 
"eqw","poq","djw","456"

And another flowfile:

"d","e","f","g" 
"123","VVV","010","dv2" 
"412","GGG","188","kw2"

I need to merge them into a single flowfile where columns "d" are the same.
So I would get:

"a","b","c","d","e","f","g" 
"abc","jfx","daw","123","VVV","010","dv2" 
"eqw","poq","djw","456","","",""

The problem is, if the file1 doesn't find the same value od "d" in file2, I would like to look at other file2-s (not all the flowfiles will have the same values, but all of them will have the same columns)
Thanks

I have tried MergeContent but it doesn't spit the right result. I am trying with fork enrichment and join enrichment but I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If one of your FlowFiles is a static CSV file, you could use [LookupRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.22.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.LookupRecord/index.html) with the other and configure the [CSVRecordLookupService](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-lookup-services-nar/1.22.0/org.apache.nifi.lookup.CSVRecordLookupService/index.html) to match on column `d`. For more complex enrichment scenarios check out the [ForkEnrichment](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.22.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ForkEnrichment/index.html) and [JoinEnrichment](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.22.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.JoinEnrichment/index.html) processors.